# Android - testing - error

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

I am trying to run an android test.  The console says the test completed successfully, but I am getting an error 1/1 under the test window.  It doesn't show that the success either passed or failed.  I don't see a red x in the code window itself so not sure what is causing it.  Here is the source code.  The app name string is defined in string.xml so that's not the cause of the problem.
thanks for your help.  It says the error is occuring at/in the testValidAppName method but nothing red shows up there.

```
public class MyApp2015R1_Test extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyApp2015R1_Test( ) {
        super(MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();


    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();

    }

    @Override
    public void runTestOnUiThread(Runnable r) throws Throwable {
        super.runTestOnUiThread(r);

    }


    public void testValidAppName(){
        TextView textView = (TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(com.example.appname.R.id.splash_txtViewAppName);
    assertTrue(textView.toString() != "");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Calling `assertTrue` in the way you're doing:

```
assertTrue(textView.toString() != "");
```

Will always result in the assertion being `true` since `textView.toString()` will return a value similar to the following: "android.widget.EditText@42314a10" - which is clearly not equal to an empty string.

Change your `assertTrue` call to the following:

```
assertTrue(!txtScannedItem.getText().toString().equals(""));
```

If you're attempting to assert if the `textView` is not `null` you should use:

```
assertTrue(txtScannedItem != null);
```

Comment: hi.  thanks for the feedback.  I tried using both assertTrue(textView.getText().toString() != null); and assertTrue(textView.toString() != null); but i still get the error.  any other ideas what might be causing it?  thanks.

Comment: ps.  if I try just assertTrue(true); the error goes away, so you're right that it's something to do with my argument.  also, is their any chance it's complaining because I'm not doing this in the runTestOnUiThread method?

Comment: I couldn't be entirely sure without seeing an actual error message. You could always try `runTestOnUiThread` but I'm not convinced that'd fix it. Your other option is to try this in [Android Studio.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)